# Base IBAction of Button Item on Title of Other Button Item

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Hopefully this is an easy one.

Here's the deal: I've got a button item, "Select", that opens a picker. When the user selects something from the picker, the title of "Select" button changes to the selection and the picker animates out of view. Now I've created a second "Search" button that will query the Google Places API, but I need it to NOT query ITS title as its doing now, but the title of the OTHER button. Make sense?

This is the relevant code. I'm positive it's a simple tweak, but I'm new to Objective-C, so I'm still wrapping my head around how things operate.

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "RendezvousViewController.h"

@interface RendezvousViewController ()

@end

@implementation RendezvousViewController

// returns the number of 'columns' to display.
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

// returns the # of rows in each component..
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.userSelectArray count];
}

-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row   forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.userSelectArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row   inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    NSLog(@"Selected Row %ld", (long)row);
    switch(row)
    {

        case 0:
            self.userSelection.title = @"Breakfast";
            break;
        case 1:
            self.userSelection.title = @"Brunch";
            break;
        case 2:
            self.userSelection.title = @"Lunch";
            break;
        case 3:
            self.userSelection.title = @"Dinner";
            break;
        case 4:
            self.userSelection.title = @"Bar";
            break;
        case 5:
            self.userSelection.title = @"Late Night Snack";
            break;
    }

}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    self.userSelectArray  = [[NSArray alloc]         initWithObjects:@"Breakfast",@"Brunch",@"Lunch",@"Dinner",@"Bar",@"Late Night Snack" , nil];

    //Make this controller the delegate for the map view.
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    // Ensure that you can view your own location in the map view.
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    //Instantiate a location object.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    //Make this controller the delegate for the location manager.
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    //Set some parameters for the location object.
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    firstLaunch=YES;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)toolbarButtonPress:(id)sender {
    UIBarButtonItem *button = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
    NSString *buttonTitle = [button.title lowercaseString];
    [self queryGooglePlaces:buttonTitle];
    //Use the above title text to build the URL query and get the data from Google.
}
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@interface RendezvousViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>

{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCentre;
    int currenDist;
    BOOL firstLaunch;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *userSelection;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *searchButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *userPicker;
@property (strong, nonatomic)          NSArray *userSelectArray;

@end
```

As always, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the button a property on your view, you could just access it directly (instead of using sender).

But why not get it directly from the picker instead of indirectly from the button title?

EDIT:

So based on your code, you want to add another button

```
@implementation RendezvousViewController{
     UIButton *selectButton;
}
```

Initalize it

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     selectButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
     ...
}
```

Then set the title in the picker

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row   inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    NSLog(@"Selected Row %ld", (long)row);
    switch(row)
    {
        case 0:
            self.selectButton.title = @"Breakfast";
            break;
      ...
    }
}
```

Then grab it when your other button is selected:

```
- (IBAction)toolbarButtonPress:(id)sender {
    NSString *buttonTitle = [self.selectButton.title lowercaseString];
    [self queryGooglePlaces:buttonTitle];
    //Use the above title text to build the URL query and get the data from Google.
}



@implementation RendezvousViewController{
     UIButton *selectButton;
     NSString *selection;
}
```

I would suggest however, to have another property to just store the value that was selected instead of relying on your UI, like the button title.  It would look like this:

Initalize it

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
     selectButton = [[UIButton alloc] init];
     selection = @"";
     ...
}
```

Then set the title in the picker

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row   inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

    NSLog(@"Selected Row %ld", (long)row);
    switch(row)
    {
        case 0:
            selection = @"Breakfast";


            break;
      ...
    }
    self.selectButton.title = selection;
}
```

Then grab it when your other button is selected:

```
- (IBAction)toolbarButtonPress:(id)sender {
    [self queryGooglePlaces:selection];
    //Use the above title text to build the URL query and get the data from Google.
}
```

Comment: The first button DOES take its title directly from the picker once a selection is made (Starts as "Select" and then changes to whatever the user selected). The second button then needs to take that selection and search for it. I did it this way just so the user would be able to see their selection once the picker slid away, but now I can't get the "Search" button to search for what was picked rather than its own title.

Comment: I understand, but the sender will always be the button that was pushed,  so you'll need to get the search term from somewhere else.  Why not get the search term from the picker AND update the button name.  But this way if you decide to change the button name format for some reason in the future, this function will still work as expected because it's not dependent on the button name. If you post more of your code I can try and give an example of what I mean.

Comment: Ah, I think that makes sense. I just edited the question to include more relevant code. Sorry if it's overload. I just wanted to include parts relevant to the picker and the button, but hadn't realized just how much that was. Funny how Apple makes some things so simple and others so complicated!

Comment: Hmm, so I'm a little confused, you keep taking about two buttons, but I only see one UIBarButtonItem.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you are asking for.

Comment: Does this help?  I might still be confused, I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you so much! Let me implement it and I'll mark it as the answer once I get it running. It makes logical sense, but I want to leave a working solution for future searchers!

Comment: Worked like a charm on both accounts! I edited to flip "self.selectButton.title = selection" to read "selection = self.selectButton.title" but otherwise, it was perfect and easy enough. Thanks for hanging with me on this one.

Answer (score 0):

```
if([buttonTitle isEqualToString:"Select"])
  return; //no searching
else{
  [self queryGooglePlaces:buttonTitle];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, santhu, this is a worthy addition to my existing code to prevent searching until a selection has been made, but what I need is for the second button to reference the title of the first button OR the picker selection. Both will work, just figured referencing the first button's title would be easier with my existing code.

Comment: @ansible are you trying to access title of selection Button in toolbarButtonPress method?